# Expo/EAS Build "expo-configure-project.sh: No such file or directory" error

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, eas

```
    bash: ./Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-common-APP_NAME/expo-configure-project.sh: No such file or directory
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

When I try build on EAS, when it runs the build scripts I get this error. If I clear the Pods folder and run `pod install`, it doesn't generate this `expo-configure-project.sh` file.
This is also reproducible on the client, but fixed if I run `npx expo prebuild` which for some reason generates this file. (EAS will not run this command as the ios folder already exists)

My build worked fine before, but after reinstalling macOS and not touching my native app for a while after updating things I've encountered this problem. Also, I don't believe my local pods folder is uploaded to EAS and I don't think it should be?

I've looked around and could not find any other posts regarding this issue. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or don't completely understand the expo build process. I might of messed something up in XCode?

Answer (score 2):

```
yarn add expo-modules-autolinking
```

expo-configure-project.sh is generated by expo-modules-autolinking.